# Implementing this Layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to achieve this layout:

[image]

The nearest that i have been able to come to is this:

[image]

The layout so far is this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4" >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip" 

        >

        <ImageButton

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" 

            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingBottom="8dip" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/myimage" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to design the above layout ?

Comment: RelativeLayout would me much easier.  Very difficult to do what you want in LL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This layout actually works as per your expectations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <!-- Center layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llCenter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Left layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/llCenter"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Right layout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/llCenter"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

create three linearlayouts with orientation set to vertical and equal layout weights. the child views of each linear layouts must also have equal layoutweights. set gravity of the first and third linearlayouts to be center_vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you leave the unnecessary layouts...??
And use the following...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="95dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can leave top layout to feel like there is none... If you can't understand what i am saying, i can explain with code... further....

Comment: hey Nabin can you please elaborate. I added image buttons but i am not getting it

Comment: This is very inefficient and would be slow at runtime.

Comment: OK.. according to your required layout's photo, you have 3 layouts on either side of your middle layouts. So why don't you create 5 layouts instead to every column and not use the top and the bottom layout of the either side.. If you are still not sure what m talking about, then i can provide you the code too.. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

What about extending [ViewGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)?

If you check the documentation there is an example of how you should create your custom children container.

Basically in your layout you have the following rules:

- The gravity of the children is centered vertically
- For the odd columns the middle element overlap with the line that goes from left to right centered vertically
- For the even columns you have got n/2 elements over that line and the remaining ones (n/2) below the same one

If you are able to do that implementing a custom layout, at the cost of more time for development, you'll have a better result and it doesn't matter the number of elements that you want to add... you'll have a layout that can manage different situations.

I suggest you to have a look at [custom attributes](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr) as well, in order to allow the integration of the attributes that you'll need directly into the XML declaration.